# How to get TRichViewEdit word coordinates?

Tags: delphi

is it possible to get the XY coordinates in screen of a word in a [`TRichViewEdit`](http://www.trichview.com/)?

If so, how can it be done?

Comment: It seems like a serious product. don't they have support there? - although no one can beat @TLama ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`GetItemCoords`](http://www.trichview.com/help/idh_trichview_getitemcoords.html) method to get the position of an item in the formatted document:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  RichViewEdit1.Add('Hello ', 0);
  RichViewEdit1.Add('world!', 0);
  RichViewEdit1.Format;

  RichViewEdit1.GetItemCoords(2, X, Y);
  ShowMessage('Position of the second word: [' + IntToStr(X) + '; ' +
    IntToStr(Y) + ']');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as an item can be composed of many words, it's not easy (if possible at all) to get a single word's coordinates. Isn't there anything else like `GetWordCoords(ItemNo, ItemOff,var X, var Y)`?